# Newline vs. new paragraph in Octopress markdown

Tags: markdown, octopress

In some markdown documentations they say that a newline is a new line, and two newlines is interpreted as a new paragraph.

But in Octopress one newline does nothing, and two newlines make a new paragraph. How can I have a single newline and not a paragraph in its markdown?

For example, if I start a bullet and have only one newline before it, it doesn't interpret it right, and the generated output is a continues text with no bullets. So currently I have to have:

```
sample text

* b1
* b2
```

instead of:

```
sample text
* b1
* b2
```

The latter is what I want to have, not the former. But the latter won't be interpreted correctly, or at least according to my expectation. The output I want to have would look like:

```
sample text
* b1
* b2
```

But what I get is:

```
sample text * b1 * b2
```

Do I have to change something in octopress settings, or what?

Comment: What *is* your expectation? Do you expect to see a `<br>` in the output? Please show the expected output in your question.

Comment: Exactly, I added it to the question, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Two or more spaces at the end of the line, before hitting enter should create a line break.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and try to fix it for a while. I think you cannot change it in Octopress. That's the way it is and you just need to get used to this.